# Qt 5.8 и Visual Studio 2015. Компиляция под win32 для Windows XP

Tags: qt5, visual-studio-2015

Необходимо скомпилировать приложение под win32. Пытался сменить настройки компилятора (`qmake -set QMAKE_SPEC win32-g++`), но не выходит)) Visual уже настроил на win32, а Qt отказывается. Может есть еще способы (простую подмену конфига уже делал, а в Qt Creator в управлении комплектов изменял Qt mkspec, но он сам затирался)?

PS:: Все компилируется, но на xp запускаться отказывается под предлогом "не win32"

Comment: Опишите подробней. Что в логах пишет при попытке компиляции?

Comment: Так в том то и дело, все нормально компилируется, а виртуальная xp ругается "не win32 приложение"

Comment: проверьте в настройке сборки проекта (в левой панели значок комьютера если память не изменяет) какой у вас компилятор выбран (там наверняка 64 битный указан) , компиляторы самобнаруживаются в настройках Qt или добавляются вручную. а потом при создании нового проекта просто нужно его указать, ну и что бы отсечь все остальное нужно удалить все неподходящие компиляторы кроме нужного (из сборки проекта). Вот тут немного полезного есть http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36125236/adding-mingw-compiler-to-qt-5-6-0-windows

Comment: Все я это уже давно проверил.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что по дефолту он компилит с тулсетом vc140, а не с vc140_xp.
Текущие версии Qt умеют с поддержкой xp собираться, но я делал так:

- в нужный qmake.conf добавлял нужные правки, чтобы генерировался makefile правильный. 
  Например, для линковщика надо указать правильную версию. 
  qtbase/mkspecs/win32-msvc2012/qmake.conf:
  QMAKE_LFLAGS_CONSOLE    = /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE\",5.01\"
  QMAKE_LFLAGS_WINDOWS    = /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS\",5.01\"
- в проекте в pch.h или в pro делал дефайл _WIN32_WINNT на xp, например так:

  #define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0502
  (так например он не будет инлайнить вызовы InitCriticalSectionEx, которая только в висте появилась, вместо InitCriticalSection).

Ну и если depends показывает, что проблема есть уже с qt'шными библиотеками, то сам qt после этого надо пересоздать (я обычно сперва правил qmakespec'и и потом уже собирал сам qt.

Ну и если надо собрать проект разово, то можно сгенерить vcxproj (qmake -tp vc) открыть проект в студии, и там заменить toolset с vc140 на vc140_xp. Тогда тоже должно работать.

Comment: Вроде уже менял тулсет на xp, но проверю еще раз.

Comment: К сожалению не помогло (Одноразовая сборка). А про более длинный вариант: это уже раньше пробовал

Comment: Убедитесь, что в настройках vcxproj-проекта для exe-шника в настроках Linker->System настройка Mimimum Required Version стоит во что-то типа 5.01.

Comment: Если там уже стоит 5.01, то следующий шаг будет собрать вывод комманды: dumpbin /headers <ваше_приложение.exe>. В нём будут интересовать значения "operating system version", "subsystem version" и другие. Если там будет 6.00, то что-то неправильно сделали, надо настройки проекта ещё раз смотреть. Ну а если dumpbin покажет 5.01 везде, то надо будет смотреть зависимости depends'ом, или даже запустить из под него.

Comment: Нет, там стоит версия 5.02, а в exe все по 6.00. После всех изменений все равно 6.00. Волшебный Qt

Comment: 1) раз в exe 6.00, то нужно сгенерить vcxproj и выложить его куда нибудь.